# PHP5-GD - package missing

Tags: installation, gd, php-5.5

I am not sure i I need to ask this here.

I trying to install php5-gd with this command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

But, system says that there is no this package

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
The following NEW packages will be installed:   php5-gd 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 28,3 kB of archives. 
After this operation, 163 kB of additional disk space will be used. WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!   
php5-gd Install these packages without verification? [y/N] Y 

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/ trusty/main php5-gd amd64 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] E: Failed to fetch 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-gd_5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]111

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
--fix-missing?
```

I tried also `--fix-mising` but still no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository is outdated, follow this guide on how to update it: https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/PPA-migration-to-ppa:ondrej-php#compatibility-php5--packages